# Could we do something about the kerning of slashes on some sites?

Tags: feature-request, design, hyperlinks, fonts, mac

Some sites in the network, like Philosophy.SE use the Palatino font, and the way it renders URLs on various browsers on my Mac (Safari, Chrome and Firefox) is ... kinda awkward. There's [too much whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) - it looks like there is a space character before and after every slash.)

[image]

([source](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/revisions/97140/6); [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/3865/21030) is another example on Christianity.SE)

Could something be changed about this [ker ning](https://xkcd.com/1015/), or would that be against the terms of usage of this font? Of course, if everybody would properly format their URLs, it wouldn't be a problem, but still ...

Comment: No repro, I see it [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL4i8.png), nothing wrong with the URL. Also, why you write typo on purpose? It's not really funny and very con fusing.

Comment: Anyway.... if there is a font causing trouble, we can simply ask SE to use less fancy font, without making it complex. Surely there are enough standard fonts out there?

Comment: I tested various browsers, but apparently it's a Mac thingy, then. It's a wordplay on the better known term "keming", I hoped the link was enough to make it clear.

Comment: I know what kerning is, but the breaking of the word is just too confusing IMO. Anyway looks like I don't have that fancy font that's why it's non-issue for me, I'm on Windows 10 (the OS determines fonts, not browser) so maybe only Mac has this font installed by default indeed.

Comment: Palatino kerns that way in TextEdit, so I doubt there's anything can be done other than change the font used.